# How to Redirect all IE users to a new page

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, redirect

My programmer is on vacation so I need your help!  I discovered a page that has a bug for IE users.  I want to redirect all IE users to a different page.

How can I do this?  I searched all through Google and Stackoverflow and cannot find an answer.   (I found some scripts, and tried them, but none worked).

Comment: maybe it will be easier/better to fix ie bug. You can try to ask separate question about that bug

Comment: Is PHP an option? Because a javascript solution will only work if javascript is enabled...

Comment: @Dennis, I've suggested a non-JS solution as an answer below

Comment: @ChrisW: +1 for it. But you can also disable the META REFRESH. And there's browsers that just don't respect the tag. For instance, it doesn't work in Google Chrome.

Comment: @Dennis - thanks, I didn't realise Chrome didn't respect it!

Comment: @Dennis But since we're looking for something applicable for IE, then it doesn't matter that Chrome ignores it. In fact, it's even more desirable that Chrome will ignore the tag.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I didn't think of doing it that way!

Comment: HALLELUJAH!!!  That worked!  Thank you so much - I knew there was a simple way to do it!

Comment: @Gregg: Please mark as answer the post that solved your problem.

Comment: Note it's for IE9 or less.

Comment: Would I put this code in the <head></head> tags?

Answer (score 37):

Or, a non-JS solution, put the following in your `head` section:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.google.com">
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Great, I was looking for non JS solution :) Don't you know if there is any way to redirect it before main page load. IE8 shows the main index page for a second and then redirects.

Comment: it looks better, and lighter.

Answer (score 7):

A reminder that the [if IE] solution does not apply to IE 10 or greater. This can be very annoying for "features" that have not been fixed by IE 10. I am going to try the php and java solutions and re-comment.

Answer (score 7):

I put this in header and it works for all IE versions:

```
<!-- For IE <= 9 -->
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "https://google.com";
</script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- For IE > 9 -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.navigator.msPointerEnabled) {
        window.location = "https://google.com";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

For Internet Explorer 10 this one works well

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
   {

      self.location = "http://www.itmaestro.in"

   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Server-side solution using PHP that's guaranteed to work on all browsers:

```
<?
if ( preg_match("/MSIE/",$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) )
        header("Location: indexIE.html");
else
        header("Location: indexNonIE.html");
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Not **totally** guaranteed to work, the HTTP_USER_AGENT can be edited (e.g. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/

Comment: Granted. But all IE users will get redirected, no matter what they disable in their browser. Or is there a way to mess with the USER_AGENT in IE too?

Comment: Apparently, there is a way (http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/799/, although I haven't tested this), although I doubt many people (especially IE users!) would actually ever bother to do this!

Comment: Well, I guess using a local proxy would also be an option. But equally unlikely for most people.

Comment: All this is assuming that Gregg is using PHP in the first place.

Comment: @Ayman Safadi: Well, of course. But if he is / can, I still think this is the best way.

Comment: an issue may be that IE11 has changed the user agent string, but they did it because they claim to be more standards based

Comment: My IE11 default user agent's string is "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko" (WTF IE) , so this doesn't work for it. And anyways, you can easily change the user string there, so this isn't a guaranteed solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Support for conditional comments has been removed in Internet Explorer 10 standards](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I'm use this dirty hack for redirecting IE10+ users

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var check = true;
</script>
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var check = false;
</script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (check) {
        window.location = "page_for_ie10+.html";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

js code:

```
<script>if (/*@cc_on!@*/false || (!!window.MSInputMethodContext && !!document.documentMode)){window.location.href="https://....html";}</script>
```

You can also use this [Boycott-IE:upgrade-your-browser](https://github.com/cjh0613/Boycott-IE)