# Redirect IE8 users to another page

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, internet-explorer-8, conditional-comments

I am implementing a website with Wordpress, but my website is not supported in Internet Explorer 8.

Is there any code I can use so that any IE8 users will be redirected to another page?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I know you specified PHP, but here's a HTML/JS solution:

```html
<!--[if IE]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7637619/1563422).

If you specifically only want to redirect IE **8** users, change `<!--[if IE]>` to `<!--[if IE 8]>`.

Comment: Access is denied. (IE8)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in PHP you can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` to detect the browser and redirect accordingly.
In javascript you can you `navigator.userAgent` to apply the same thing.