# How to Redirect URL depending on browser used

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, browser, internet-explorer-8

I am getting uphill from my clients due to the new wordpress themes not running in IE8. I need to direct all modern browsers to the new site, and direct all IE browsers to an IE friendly site. Could anyone please advise?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect IE8 users to another page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471488/redirect-ie8-users-to-another-page)

Answer (score 0):

Put this script in your site's `<head>`.
If IE will found it wll redirect users to IE friendly site.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ($.browser.msie) {
   window.location.href = "IE friendly site";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I work mainly in the simple-code side of wordpress, using basic html, and php. What php file / filename should I add this code to for it to work correctly?

Comment: The `<head>` element in WordPress is located in the theme's [header.php file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Document_Head_.28header.php.29).

Comment: Thank you kind sir's. You are both the definite quality.

Comment: Put it in your wordpress theme's folder in `header.php' after `wp_head()`. If your issue is solved than `mark question as solved.`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to TechnoKnol answer, please note that jQuery.browser property was removed from jQuery library 1.9+. To use that property you need jQuery.migrate plugin https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme

You can also detect the user's browser with PHP get_browser function. If you want to target IE i guess you can do something like this:

```
<?php 
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent)) 
{
  wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com', 301 ); exit; 
}
?>
```