# How can I restrict my web application not to open in internet explorer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, internet-explorer, mean-stack, cloudflare

I have an application developed on MEAN Stack. My application design is not responsive and it doesn't fit good when open in Internet Explorer. If Users try to open my application in Internet Explorer then I want to redirect them to a static html page. It is an in-house application so it is fine with the users to not use the IE for this app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Redirect all IE users to a new page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637585/how-to-redirect-all-ie-users-to-a-new-page)

Comment: Can you share more information about the infrastructure? Load balancer, Etc.

Comment: You can use [DetectJS](https://github.com/darcyclarke/Detect.js/) for this.

Comment: The best way to accomplish that is throughout a layer before requests hit your Web server.  That way, you have more control and avoid putting that responsibility on your App.  You can do that with Nginx evaluating the `$http_user_agent` variable. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/nginx-if-conditional-http_user_agent-requests/